# cloud9 Heroku deployment fails

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, cloud9-ide, meanjs

I developed a meanjs app on **Cloud 9**. I am trying to deploy my app directly on cloud 9 using heorku. Even though I followed instruction on the cloud 9 webpage, I get error:

```
Opening morning-tor-4953... xprop:  unable to open display ''
xprop:  unable to open display ''
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com/'
done
```

I already ran mongodb server, but I still get error saying that "Could not connect to MongoDB!"
If I hit heroku logs, get:

```
2015-11-19T02:38:59.583495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=161f64ce-741e-4fdc-9ca6-9c895faa1ae5 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-19T02:38:59.574516+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579597+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579601+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579603+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579606+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579602+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579607+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579608+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579609+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579609+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-11-19T02:38:59.579610+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
2015-11-19T02:38:59.584641+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-11-19T02:38:59.692801+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-11-19T02:38:59.587909+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #1
2015-11-19T02:39:00.999132+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 49295
2015-11-19T02:39:01.003451+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not connect to MongoDB!
2015-11-19T02:39:01.003546+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:39:03.770258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=a7da53eb-d4db-41ed-974d-a030a42ceb80 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=43ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-19T02:39:03.752380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-19T02:39:03.753346+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2015-11-19T02:39:03.755515+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757380+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757383+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757384+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757384+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757386+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757385+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757388+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757388+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-11-19T02:39:03.757389+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
2015-11-19T02:39:03.768047+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-11-19T02:39:03.974171+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-11-19T02:39:03.752606+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
2015-11-19T02:39:03.777694+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #2
2015-11-19T02:39:05.613044+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 49295
2015-11-19T02:39:05.617739+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:39:05.617448+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not connect to MongoDB!
2015-11-19T02:40:02.990789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=2a339f1a-48d1-45b3-9f59-8615d5fcd368 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-19T02:40:02.970997+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2015-11-19T02:40:02.970290+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979524+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979521+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979525+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979526+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979527+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979528+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979529+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979529+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-11-19T02:40:02.979530+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
2015-11-19T02:40:02.970566+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
2015-11-19T02:40:02.990026+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-11-19T02:40:03.130024+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-11-19T02:40:02.976366+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-11-19T02:40:02.994300+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #3
2015-11-19T02:40:04.195764+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 49295
2015-11-19T02:40:04.199716+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not connect to MongoDB!
2015-11-19T02:40:04.199776+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179702+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179705+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179707+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179707+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179710+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179709+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179708+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179710+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179711+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179712+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179714+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.179713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-11-19T02:40:08.195613+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-11-19T02:40:08.403848+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2015-11-19T02:40:08.198542+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Script restart attempt #4
2015-11-19T02:40:08.196245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=10a0b882-9c31-44d8-9e91-438506b1f0fc fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=53ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-19T02:40:10.813150+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 49295
2015-11-19T02:40:10.814675+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:40:10.814328+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not connect to MongoDB!
2015-11-19T02:50:22.474045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=85f06246-b903-4778-9d4a-ad9f490e07e0 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=39ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-19T02:50:22.458714+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-11-19T02:50:22.459778+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err;
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464081+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464083+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464085+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464084+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:106:17)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464086+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emit (events.js:98:17)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464088+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464087+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.472755+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2015-11-19T02:50:22.464089+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
2015-11-19T02:50:22.459125+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
2015-11-19T02:50:22.462353+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-11-19T02:51:05.724024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H21 desc="Backend connection refused" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=bf1e57b4-1812-4bcb-a960-a9b6d0e4dd50 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-19T02:53:48.794265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H21 desc="Backend connection refused" method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=28f7eb8c-fbc6-423b-bde6-4295e56d07b1 fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-19T02:54:19.312933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H21 desc="Backend connection refused" method=GET path="/" host=morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com request_id=4aadb262-7f39-459f-ac5d-a95b0ce2383f fwd="73.162.6.191" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms s rvice= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-19T02:56:30.735444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-11-19T02:58:47.943599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-19T02:58:50.739096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Can you spot what cause this problem, and how to solve this issue? I downloaded whole file and tried to deploy locally, but it failed again. I think the problem is that I need some modification to Mongodb setup to deploy from my local computer because cloud 9 has different environment. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error while developing a rails app on c9 for the first time. You simply have to click on the URL of your app (https://morning-tor-4953.herokuapp.com/) and then from them click open.